# how to enable module in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

content is not displayed in system->configuration tab in magento-admin

how can we to enable and disable module, if content is not displayed?

is their any way to display content in this tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to database and find "core_config_data" table.

Find your module name and change value from "1" to "0" or "0" to "1".

Answer (score 1):

you can disable module through in module.xml file just remove that xml file

module xml file located at app/etc/modules/yourmodule_name_.xml

Comment: I don't want to disable, I want to enable it.

Comment: just open your yourmodulename.xml file and write  <active>true</active> insted of false,,,if you want disable then write false

Comment: it is true only at that place.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the Magento admin panel. Go to System -> Configuration. Scroll to the bottom of the left hand navigation and click Advanced. Find the module name and ensure that the drop down is set to enabled. Click save.

Comment: configuration content is not displayed, that is why I am not able to enable or disable from here.

Comment: Also <active>true</active> is true on its xml page